# What are the advantages and disadvantages of Duo-Queuing?

Tags: league-of-legends

Recently I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IKihzPey20) video that tells to never do duo rank games.

But I find few advantages on duo rank games:

- It's nice to play with a friend.
- Good communication via Skype or other voice chats.
- It's one less troll in your team (assuming your friend isn't one).
- I think I win more games while Duo-Queuing.

In general, what are the pros and cons of playing duo ranks?

What are the optimal conditions in order to maximise the advantages and lower the cons of duo ranking? (Maybe playing with someone lower in rank than you, but having same skills (someone who is climbing quickly the ladder for instance))

Comment: Kind of a con: People tend to instantly flame pre-mades for some reason, a tip is to never mention it in-game.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Duoqueuing can have more advantages than disadvantages but you have to do it right. I'll first tell you some of the Pros and Cons of Duoqueue.

### Pro

You have already listed most of the positive aspects of duoqueue. Now there are still some that are important:

- **Map Awareness** - Two people watching the map are better than one. This is especially true in combination with the improved communication per voice chat. This improved map awareness can win you games since there are 2 people in your team where the risk of getting ganked/caught is reduced.
- **Insane Roaming** - Coordinated ganks are extremely effective in soloqueue. If you pull off a good 2 man gank against a laner you will be able to snowball extremely hard.

### Con

Unfortunately there are a lot of negative aspects when playing Duoqueue most of them can be avoided but as mentioned above: you'll have to play accordingly.

- **Stronger enemies/Enemy Duo** - There are two options: Either you will face another duo in the enemy team or the enemy MMR will be higher. The first option is the one you should prefer since your entire team will be facing off against stronger enemies (as described in the video). Unfortunately there's no way of avoiding this when playing duoqueue.
- **Everyone hates you** - I can't blame them. Most duos are toxic and think they can carry games themselves since they have *superior communication* but they ignore the MMR disadvantage. If you really want to go botlane don't write "Pre bot with Player X" but you and your buddy should just both write "Pref supp" and "Pref ADC". This increases your chances of getting the lane without demoralizing your team. During champion select you should see it as a soloqueue game and ignore your duo partner.
- **Risk of you/your duo feeding** - It's almost impossible to have the same MMR and most duo players don't even have the same elo. One of you will always be lower unless he's really skilled for his elo he will perform worse than the rest of the team. This is a big problem because people tend to ignore the fact that their partner fed and blame others. Again this demoralizes the entire team and your chances of winning decrease drastically.
- **MMR Inaccuracy** - Playing duoqueue will cause the matchmaking to find a mean value of your combined MMR. If you are Platinum 1 and your Partner is Gold 5 (both normal MMR) you will most likely play against a lot of platinum 5 players. This is a problem since winning multiple games like this will provide the gold player (who is usually carried by the platinum player) with a higher MMR than he's actually at. If he starts playing again he will most likely lose since he's not used to the higher skill cap needed for the above elo. When climbing elo solo you won't make any progress unless you improve. The same goes for the platinum player who has a lower MMR after the games than before and he won't progress as fast as before when playing solo.

### How to duo correctly

- **Pick roles you're comfortable with** - Most duo partners want to go premade botlane, since it's the only duolane in the current meta. Going bot is usually the least benficial lane as a duo team unless you're Support and ADC mains. Toplane, Midlane and Jungle have a higher impact on the game most of the time. Arguably the best combination would be Mid + Jungle since it offers you a great overview of the game and roaming is easy. But again: Pick whatever your main champion is and respect the pick order. Being a duo team doesn't automatically allow you to go wherever you want to.
- **Respect the other teammembers** - Flaming is extremely harmful in soloqueue. If you or your duo partner does a mistake and gets flamed don't flame back or defend him. Tell your partner to mute the flamer and do the same. Also if your partner does the same mistake over and over again, don't be afraid to tell him (without flaming) where he could improve.
- **You need synergy** - This is especially true when playing duo bot but it's applicable to every lane. To play duo queue effectively you're gonna need the best synergy possible. Don't play with the dude who added you after a good game. You don't know him and you don't know how well he plays over the course of a few games.

Comment: Great answer! Any website that can gives you your winrate with our duo queue partner?

Comment: @dyesdyes I don't know any website that has a record of all the duo queue games you've played but  [op.gg](http://op.gg/) has the most recent ones (Only winrate though)

Comment: " Also if your partner does the same mistake over and over again, don't be afraid to tell him (without flaming) where he could improve." Optionally, do this in the in-game chat. It helps your team-mates to see that you are not the kind of premade that only criticizes others and not each other.

Comment: [op.gg](http://op.gg) isn't reliable, I've played duo queue (last 2 games) and it doesn't show correctly.

Comment: +1 for "During champion select you should see it as a soloqueue game and ignore your duo partner." This is how I duo, always.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially there is one huge disadvantage to dual queuing - which is that your team gets an ELO penalty compared to the other team.

In other words if the opposing team does not also have a duo then they will be individually more skilled than your team.

In order to make duo worth it you need to bring advantages to the table that outweigh that penalty. This means that you need superior teamwork, game knowledge, and ability - not just for your lane but for the whole game.

So duo bot makes sense in terms of winning that lane. You are (or should be) on voice comms together. You are (or should be) used to working together and know how to get that synergy you need to dominate in lane.

But the price of that is both the other lanes potentially being outmatched. You've traded one winning lane for 2 losing ones. Unless you are able to take your bot lane and really dominate, start taking dragons, roaming to mid, etc, then your team as a whole has lost out.

Doing mid or top+jungler is actually a fairly strong duo combination as well. You can work nicely co-ordinating ganks or invasions. But you still have the same problem, you've gained in one lane to lose in two others.

If you go top+mid, that's even worse as now you're extra co-ordination is really weak in the early game. It can work but only if you both start roaming early.

So that's the trade-off with going duo queue. It's not enough to win your lane. You need to use the extra co-ordination between the two of you to win the whole map. For example a successful jungle+mid will:

Steal an enemy buff, defend own buffs, ward map and invade on enemy jungler. As soon as you hit 6 you'll both move together to do a 4 man gank on enemy bot lane then take dragon, etc.

You need to get your team ahead, not just yourselves.

Comment: "if the opposing team does not also have a duo then they will be individually more skilled than your team" Do you have a source to back this up? As far as I understand the matchmaking system in LoL it tries to find another team with a duo-queue if you have a duo-queue on your team.

Comment: But I mean, even if they have a higher MMR than you because of the penalty, at most, it will be one division difference. There really isn't that much of a difference between a gold V and gold IV or plat 4 and plat 3. Also, any idea where I can find out my stats for duo rank games?

Comment: @Kevin I've been in many games where one side has a duo and the other has not. It used to be easy to see when it was displayed on certain websites but they hide it these days.

Comment: @TimB The experiences of an individual can't be taken seriously as a source. This answer is based on speculation.

Comment: Jungle + anywhere else as duo is the best imo, the jungler can help all lanes, making the mmr difference almost nil by helping the lane having the most troubles.

Comment: @kevin I've personally played in games where one side has a duo and the other has not. I don't know how much more seriously a source you want than direct experience. Try googling to find plenty of other people discussing the matchmaking in the case of duo queuing.

Comment: @TimB A source is either a statement from Riot or data from thousands of users combined in some form of graph. The experiences of some people you found via google are NOT sources, they are called theories. Also, I'm not saying it's impossible that one side has a duo and one side doesn't, I said that the matchmaking system TRIES to find a team with a duo if you duo-queue.

Comment: @Kevin Technically you're the one making the hypothesis with no evidence. The only falsifiable hypothesis is that it always puts duo against duo - and we can disprove that with a single counter example which I've provided. Anything else is speculation and the only information I've seen says that you get an MMR adjustment. I've seen nothing either way about trying to match duo with duo but considering the system if it wanted to do that could _always_ put duo against duo that suggests (without proving) that it does not. Why bother favoring duo v duo when you could just make it always do that?

Comment: You stated "if the opposing team does not also have a duo then they will be individually more skilled than your team", this may or may not be true, we don't know that because there is no source available. I questioned it and asked if you could provide a source, I told you why I'm questioning you because I think that is how to properly provide constructive criticism. Do with that criticism what you want, I'm really not looking for a discussion since that is not what the comment section is for. I never said that it "always puts duo against duo", you are putting those words in my mouth.

Comment: @kevin that's not what you questioned. You questioned whether it puts duos against singles. https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752954-Matchmaking-Guide#q4 - If a player is queued alone, the strength is determined by his personal matchmaking rating (referred to as MMR from here on out) and number of wins for that particular queue. If the player is queued with a pre-made team, the system will adjust the MMR of the team accordingly. In most cases, we have found pre-made teams out-perform teams composed of unconnected players.

Answer (score 4):

Your points are valid. But there also are disadvantages:

**Less/Far too much LP**

Less LP is a horrible feeling. I was in Diamond II, 95 LP in Season IV and gained 1 LP per match (Non-Duo). When i was at 98 LP, the game had the audaciousness to give me 0 LP for that win, which was the point I went into completely ragemode. The same can happen when you queue with someone who is lower than you. The game will give you less LP in a win, but also more LP loss in a defeat. Your friend has the advantage to gain more LP and lose less, but if he doesn't play on that level, he is screwed once he plays on his own without you.

**Nobody likes premades**

It's tough, but in reality - almost everybody hates premades, including me. They tend to flame everyone else except themselves (e.g. botlane pre usually flame the jungler), will never criticize each other, so there is no constructive progress and 99% of them think they can carry on their own without playing with the team. So you will most likely get flamed if you mess it up. I wouldn't mention it in game if I were you.

**Friendship on the risk**

Yes, you might laugh at this point, but I saw friendships ending because of a game. Maybe this will not happen to you, but there might be a few arguments which might escalate.

Comment: 1) you LP issue in diamond was because of your lower MMR compared to your ranking. For the lower ranked of the duo, if he plays against better players, when he goes back to playing alone, he will probably feel like it's easier no? (as it could be an advantage too) || 
But really valid point!

Comment: 2) I agree that duo in ranks don't have a good reputation. I tend not to mention it or they start flaming right away. To be honest, it's pretty much the same with solo players. If they tend to troll, then sure, they won't improve in duo. But I just mute people as soon as they start flaming, whether i'm in a duo or solo. Life is just too short for flamers.

Comment: @dyesdyes I know that this was the issue, but the effect is the same. If you get matched with low elo players, you won't gain a lot of LP there, therefore you will be pissed off, since your victory is not rewarded properly.

Comment: None of these are actual reasons to not duo queue. You list your LP gain in high diamond as an example, but when solo queueing you get 0-2 per win as well. Other people not liking premades is not a reason not to do it, especially when it's not even the premade that is bothering people, but the flaming that often goes with it. The friendship thing is different for everyone, if you know you can handle playing a game with friends without causing conflicts then I see no reason to not play with friends.

Comment: @Kevin I never said these are reasons not to duo. I said these are the disadvantages.

Comment: And I'm saying that they don't have to be disadvantages for everyone. I'm not trying to bash you, I'm just stating for future readers that your points don't necessarily have to hold true for them as well. The  answer itself is a good answer to OP's question.

Comment: you got lower LP in D2 because your MMR is not high enough to justify the increased MMR gain. When you were getting 0LP in D2 it was because the people you were playing against were not significantly skilled enough to push you over the D1 boundary. I'm willing to bet this was before the introduction of masters as well. This isn't really to do with duo queue.. while you do get lower mmr in duo queue, this is only true if you are very far apart in terms of ranks. people in the same division will likely not notice a difference.

Comment: @DanPantry I'm rather surprised that nobody understands that i just wrote that as a simple example to make clear that these LP gains can frustrate heavily. I NEVER EVER said that my case was related to DuoQ, what i did say in the previous comments was, that the effect is the same: If you queue with someone who is lower than you, you will get people with a lower MMR, therefore your LP gains will decrease if you win, and your LP losses will increase if you lose.